# In Swift, how do I detect number of app launches in order to present an alert?

Tags: swift

Let me start by saying that I'm new to programming and maybe what I want to do isn't possible, at least not in the way I'm trying to do it! I've done quite a few searches, but I must be searching for the wrong things because I can't find an answer anywhere. :(

In a nutshell what I am trying to do is have my app count the number of times it has been launched and, when it reaches certain values, display an alert to users. My approach in doing this is described below.

I have declared a variable as follows:

```
var numberoflaunches :Int! = 0
```

And I have created the following functions:

```
func LoadNumberOfLaunches()
{
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    numberoflaunches = defaults.integerForKey("Launches")
}


func SaveNumberOfLaunches()
{
    numberoflaunches = numberoflaunches + 1
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setInteger(numberoflaunches, forKey: "Launches")
}


func ShowReviewPrompt()
{
    if (numberoflaunches == 10 || numberoflaunches == 50 || numberoflaunches == 100){

    // create the alert
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Friendly prompt", message: "Would you consider reviewing this App? It really makes a difference! If not, perhaps you'd like to send me a suggestion to improve it instead?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        // add the actions (buttons)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Review app", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler: {action in

            self.ReviewApp()

            }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Send suggestion", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler: {action in

            self.SendFeedback()

        }))

        // show the alert
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    } else {
        // For pre-iOS 8 users
        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Friendly prompt"
        alert.message = "Would you consider reviewing this App? It really makes a difference! If not, perhaps instead you'd like to send me a suggestion to improve it? You can do either from the Info page."
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
        alert.show()
        }}}
```

Finally, in my viewDidLoad I have the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    LoadNumberOfLaunches()        
    SaveNumberOfLaunches()
    ShowReviewPrompt()

}
```

Now, I'm not sure if placing the above code in the viewDidLoad is the best place, because I assume that every time the view loads it will trigger my functions, so as an aside I would be interested in better approaches.

However, getting back to the point of this question, I can run the app in both the simulator and on actual devices, but I never see my alert messages come up.

So, am I just making a newbie mistake, or should this in fact work? Or is there another way to achieve what I'm doing?

Comment: which view controller is it in? did you debug to see that your code is called and what the counter contains?

Comment: It's in the view controller for my main menu, which appears after the launch screen. I tried debugging, but the counter only displays a value when it first launches, not everytime the view loads. That seems like a good thing, but when I launch it again the counter has skipped a few numbers, hence my realisation that the viewDidLoad is not the best place for me to put the code to run my functions. But, now that I think about it, I think you're on to something. I will debug again in a new simulator without going into any other screens so I can try to catch what happens when the count is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call ShowReviewPrompt function in viewDidAppear. Calling it in viewDidLoad won't work since the view itself is not in the window hierarchy yet hence can't present another view controller

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    ShowReviewPrompt()
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, that makes sense except for the fact I don't have a viewDidAppear. I've checked all my view controllers, and none of them have it. Have I done something wrong? I'm guessing that's unusual?

Comment: you need to add it yourself

Comment: Oh, okay, well I guess the fact that I'm new to this is now really obvious! I will do a search on viewDidAppear and see what I find. Thanks!

Comment: i edited the answer you can paste it to your code. There are some functions provided by the viewcontroller class and you can override the ones you need. just dont forget to call super.viewDidAppear (or the function you are overriding) in it

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to track the number of times your app is opened, then doing this in any view controller will give you extraneous results because of the navigation flow of your app. If he user navigates away from the main page and then returns to it then `viewDidAppear` could be called *several times in one session* which I think is not what you want to achieve. So instead, you should be monitoring this in your `appDelegate` possibly in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions` which is maybe a more accurate representation of how many times the app has been opened.

Comment: Great! That sounds like a better way to get around my secondary issue. I had manipulated my counter points to allow for the extraneous results, but I think I'll go back and have a play with appDelegate instead.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5.0

Insert into method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate`

```
let value = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "appLaunchCount")
    let newValue = value + 1
    UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "appLaunchCount")
    if value == 5 { // 5 = number of launches of your application
       // your code
    }
```